# Spring Data JPA Automatic Repository with Custom Method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Everything was working fine until I needed to get my "About" entity ordered by it's "About.position" property. I added a method to my spring repository interface but after, it doesn't work.

About Entity

```
package coffee;

import javax.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(access=AccessLevel.PUBLIC, force=true)
@Entity
public class About {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @OrderBy
    private Integer position;
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;
    @NotEmpty
    private String description;
    @Lob
    private String image;
}
```

Repo Interface

```
package coffee.data;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import coffee.*;

public interface AboutRepository extends CrudRepository<About, Long> {
    List<About> getAboutByPosition ();
}
```

Error Source Code

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.6.RELEASE)

2018-11-29 18:29:15.793  INFO 672 --- [  restartedMain] coffee.CoffeeApplication                 : Starting CoffeeApplication on Peters-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 672 (started by petercho in /Users/petercho/Desktop/Spring Projects/coffee)
2018-11-29 18:29:15.794  INFO 672 --- [  restartedMain] coffee.CoffeeApplication                 : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-11-29 18:29:15.795  INFO 672 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@64702e06: startup date [Thu Nov 29 18:29:15 PST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-11-29 18:29:16.093  INFO 672 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8329b2d2] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-11-29 18:29:16.136  INFO 672 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-11-29 18:29:16.137  INFO 672 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-11-29 18:29:16.137  INFO 672 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.34
2018-11-29 18:29:16.144  INFO 672 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat-7].[localhost].[/]     : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-11-29 18:29:16.144  INFO 672 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 349 ms
2018-11-29 18:29:16.263  INFO 672 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-11-29 18:29:16.263  INFO 672 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'webMvcMetricsFilter' to: [/*]
2018-11-29 18:29:16.263  INFO 672 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-11-29 18:29:16.263  INFO 672 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-11-29 18:29:16.263  INFO 672 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-11-29 18:29:16.263  INFO 672 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpTraceFilter' to: [/*]
2018-11-29 18:29:16.263  INFO 672 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-11-29 18:29:16.263  INFO 672 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet webServlet mapped to [/h2-console/*]
2018-11-29 18:29:16.279  INFO 672 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-14 - Starting...
2018-11-29 18:29:16.280  INFO 672 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-14 - Start completed.
2018-11-29 18:29:16.282  INFO 672 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-11-29 18:29:16.282  INFO 672 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2018-11-29 18:29:16.286  INFO 672 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2018-11-29 18:29:16.302  INFO 672 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@f775558'
2018-11-29 18:29:16.302  INFO 672 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-11-29 18:29:16.324  WARN 672 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'aboutController' defined in file [/Users/petercho/Desktop/Spring Projects/coffee/target/classes/coffee/controller/AboutController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aboutRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List coffee.data.AboutRepository.findAboutByPositionAsc()! No property asc found for type Integer! Traversed path: About.position.
2018-11-29 18:29:16.324  INFO 672 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-11-29 18:29:16.324  INFO 672 --- [  restartedMain] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed drop of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2018-11-29 18:29:16.325  WARN 672 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor': org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL) [90121-197]
2018-11-29 18:29:16.325  INFO 672 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-14 - Shutdown initiated...
2018-11-29 18:29:16.325  INFO 672 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-14 - Shutdown completed.
2018-11-29 18:29:16.326  INFO 672 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-11-29 18:29:16.332  INFO 672 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-11-29 18:29:16.334 ERROR 672 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'aboutController' defined in file [/Users/petercho/Desktop/Spring Projects/coffee/target/classes/coffee/controller/AboutController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aboutRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List coffee.data.AboutRepository.findAboutByPositionAsc()! No property asc found for type Integer! Traversed path: About.position.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:733) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:198) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1266) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:548) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386) ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1242) ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1230) ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at coffee.CoffeeApplication.main(CoffeeApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aboutRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List coffee.data.AboutRepository.findAboutByPositionAsc()! No property asc found for type Integer! Traversed path: About.position.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1694) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:819) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:725) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List coffee.data.AboutRepository.findAboutByPositionAsc()! No property asc found for type Integer! Traversed path: About.position.
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:82) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:103) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:208) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:79) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:565) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:558) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1052) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:560) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:550) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:550) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:323) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$4(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:290) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:293) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:102) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1753) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1690) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property asc found for type Integer! Traversed path: About.position.
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:358) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:334) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:368) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:392) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:334) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:287) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:269) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:252) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:250) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:251) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:380) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:381) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:96) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:76) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    ... 61 common frames omitted
```

everything works fine when the method findAboutsByPosition() is left out

Answer (score 1):

getAboutByOrderByPosition() 
wrong syntax, solved!